# How to temporarly disable MixedRealityToolkit.InputSystem?

Tags: mrtk

I would like to disable all inputs during some transitions, once the user as clicked a button for example.

Of course i could disable the button, but i'm looking for a more generic solution to avoid seeing same bug come over again for each button.

i tried `PushInputDisable` / `PopInputDisable`, which seems to be what i'm looking for, but it makes `inputsimulationservice` buggy after the pop, and overall most of the input events raised from inputsystem are sadly not plugged into that disablestack.

I could make an inputhandler that implements all interfaces and use `PushModalInputHandler`, but it seems a bit overkill for what i'm trying to achieve.
Plus, it may not catch the voice commands for example.

Any simple solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to disable and enable the input system:

```
public class DisableInputSystemTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IMixedRealityInputSystem inputSystem = null;
    private IMixedRealityInputSystem InputSystem
    {
        get
        {
            if (inputSystem == null)
            {
                MixedRealityServiceRegistry.TryGetService<IMixedRealityInputSystem>(out inputSystem);
            }
            return inputSystem;
        }
    }

    public void DisableInputSystem()
    {
        InputSystem.Disable();
    }

    public void EnableInputSystem()
    {
        InputSystem.Enable();
    }
}
```

Note that in the latest `mrtk_development` branch there's a bug (issue [5085](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5085)) where after re-enabling you will get lots of null pointers saying "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.FocusProvider.RegisterPointers (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.IMixedRealityInputSource inputSource) (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/InputSystem/FocusProvider.cs:689)"

To fix, move the following code from `MixedRealityInputSystem.Initalize()` to the very beginning of `MixedRealityInputSystem.Enable()`:

```
MixedRealityInputSystemProfile profile = ConfigurationProfile as MixedRealityInputSystemProfile;

if (profile.PointerProfile != null)
{
    if (profile.PointerProfile.GazeProviderType?.Type != null)
    {
        GazeProvider = CameraCache.Main.gameObject.EnsureComponent(profile.PointerProfile.GazeProviderType.Type) as IMixedRealityGazeProvider;
        GazeProvider.GazeCursorPrefab = profile.PointerProfile.GazeCursorPrefab;
        // Current implementation implements both provider types in one concrete class.
        EyeGazeProvider = GazeProvider as IMixedRealityEyeGazeProvider;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("The Input system is missing the required GazeProviderType!");
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("The Input system is missing the required Pointer Profile!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Julia,
We didn't go the Enable Disable way, because we got a bunch of errors (on master branch RC2.1)

One time on first time enabling InputSystem:
`ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: _unity_self
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Windows.Input.GestureRecognizerExtensions.UpdateAndResetGestures (GestureRecognizerExtensions.cs:11)`

Comment: and each time after that when we call enable(after a disable) : 
`There's already a IMixedRealityInputDeviceManager.Windows Mixed Reality Device Manager registered!`

`ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Flat
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.ArticulatedHandPose.LoadGesturePose (ArticulatedHandPose.cs:218)`
or
 `There's already a IMixedRealityInputDeviceManager.Input Simulation Service registered!`

Comment: marked as the answer fur future, but generating errors at the moment.
discussions continue on https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5085

Answer (score 0):

Anything on this now, is it fixed ?

Following issue on GitHub, it looks like anything is not done about this case, any proper solution provided.

If I fix code with this one which Juila provided, I get error :

Mixed Reality Device Manager registered! ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Flat Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities.ArticulatedHandPose.LoadGesturePose (ArticulatedHandPose.cs:218)

Look like this thing is much deeper in Core of MRTK.

Interesting think is that, I lost my voice commands when I get back in Unity app from lost focus state, on one HoloLens, but on the other HoloLens, same version, same OS version, it works perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56783236/229311), if you need to disable the Input System inside an MRTK callback function (e.g., inside an [Interactable's OnClick event](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.UI.Interactable.html#Microsoft_MixedReality_Toolkit_UI_Interactable_OnClick) callback), you'll have to call `InputSystem.Disable();` in a Coroutine, otherwise you'll encounter an error. For example:

```
// OnClick callback for MRTK's Interactable
public void OnClick()
{
    // This call causes the following Exception to be raised (and not caught):
    // "InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
    //Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.CoreServices.InputSystem.Disable();

    // This call successfully disables the input system with no errors
    StartCoroutine(DisableCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator DisableCoroutine()
{
    yield return null;
    Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.CoreServices.InputSystem.Disable();
}
```

The only downside of this approach is that it'll take at least another frame to disable the MRTK Input System, but at least you won't get any errors.

For reference, the stack trace for the error encountered is as follows:

> InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException (System.ExceptionResource resource) (at :0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare () (at :0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () (at :0)
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem.LateUpdate () (at Assets/MRTK/Core/Services/BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem.cs:69)
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit+<>c.b__66_0 (Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.IMixedRealityService service) (at Assets/MRTK/Core/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:963)
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder (System.Action`1[T] execute) (at Assets/MRTK/Core/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:1034)
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.LateUpdateAllServices () (at Assets/MRTK/Core/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:963)
> Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit.LateUpdate () (at Assets/MRTK/Core/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:638)